# Why integrating by substituion doesn’t directly work for sin squared

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Given that we know this is correct:
$\int\sin^2(u)du=\frac u2-\frac{\sin (2u)}4 + C$

Why can't we use it directly to solve the following equation by u-substitution:
$\int\sin^2(2\pi ft)dt$
Where
$u=2\pi ft$
and $du=2\pi fdt$ (where $f$ is a constant).

These are the steps I used (ignoring the $+C$):
$\int\sin^2(2\pi ft)dt=\frac1{2\pi f}\int\sin^2(u)du=\frac1{2\pi f}\left(\frac u2-\frac{\sin (2u)}4\right)$

As you can see, $\frac1{2\pi f}$ distributes on both terms. While in the correct solution, it only multiply the second term.

If I use the sine half-angle to replace the sine squared by a cos, and then do the u-substitution, I get the right answer.

But I want to understand why it's not working in my more direct approach. I must have understood something wrong about how u-substitution works.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I should have specified that f is a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want a better template. Your integral works for $\sin^2 t$, but what you really want is
$$\int \sin^2 (kt) \, dt=\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\sin(2kt)}{4k}+c.$$

Now just let $k=2 \pi f$, or whatever other constant you desire.

Let me know if you want a derivation of this effect it is very straightforward.

Comment: I see, so I guess that's why constants are included in the integral cheat sheets? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Indeed :), and to show this use the trig identity $$\sin^2(kt)=\frac{1-\cos(2kt)}{2}.$$